# Trouble saving and displaying variables from jquery JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, url

I am having trouble saving a JSON value into a jquery variable.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script> 
   <script>
     var tronQty = 5000.00; //total number of tron coins
     var tronPrice; //var to hold the json price
     $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/tron/", function(data, 
     status) {
     $("#tron").html(data[0].price_usd);
     //can't figure out how to save this to a variable
     tronPrice = $("#tron").html(data[0].price_usd);
     });
     //test to see if the tronpricefromvar div will display the price
     $('#tronpricefromvar').html(tronPrice);
   </script>
  </head>
<body>
  Tron
  <br>
  Price: <div id="tron"></div>
  <br>
  Price from var: <div id="tronpricefromvar"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The json data is :

[
    {
        "id": "tron", 
        "name": "TRON", 
        "symbol": "TRX", 
        "rank": "14", 
        "price_usd": "0.0939412", 
        "price_btc": "0.00000688", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "782661000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "6176464099.0", 
        "available_supply": "65748192475.0", 
        "total_supply": "100000000000", 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "percent_change_1h": "-7.02", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-14.43", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-43.47", 
        "last_updated": "1515929954"
    }
]

I am able to pull and display the price from the JSON into the tron div I created but....

What I want to do is save that pulled data into a javascript variable so I can  multiply the price by the quantity that I have. I can store the qty in a variable but I cannot figure out how to grab the price from json off of a URL and save it to a variable. It seems simple to do but I have tried for hours and hours to figure it out with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just assign the price in a variable.Then you can use where you want.Like below

```
 <script>
     var tronQty = 5000.00; //total number of tron coins
     var tronPrice; //var to hold the json price
     $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/tron/", function(data, 
     status) {
        var price = data[0].price_usd
        $("#tron").html(price);    
        $('#tronpricefromvar').html(price);
     });

   </script>
```

One more thing .you can use this variable in your ajax request only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I use this outside the ajax request